# cannot find the symbol method console();

Tags: java, console

This is my code :---

```
import java.lang.*;
class Console
{
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            char i;
            i=System.console().readLine("this is how we give he input to the string");
            System.out.println("this is what we want to print:0)");
            System.out.println(i);

        }
}
```

and the output I am getting is this:-

Output:-

```
.java:7: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method console()
location: class java.lang.System
    i=System.console().readLine("this is how we give he input to the string");
                ^
1 error

Tool completed with exit code 1
```

If anyone can help me out...

Comment: You need to compile with Java 1.6 or 1.7 as the Console class was added then.

Comment: you are on jdk1.5 I believe , upgrade and you should be through

Answer (score 0):

Mistake with the jdk version, because it must be jdk1.6 or later, and when changed to a newer jdk,
there's a compilation problem, `System.console().readLine()` returns a `String`, but you assigned `char`

Comment: That's not the source of this error. Please see my comment in to the original question to see why he's getting this error. But you are correct, if he was able to use Console, he'd run into this error. So 1+ to you.

Comment: -1 your reason will never cause symbol not found error.

Comment: No, but it will be another mistake commited in the near future when he changes jdk version, :D

Comment: @Chandra: As I have already stated in my comment above yours, but nevertheless richarbernal's advice is sound, and he does not deserve a down-vote.

Comment: ohk guyz let me first update my jdk version

Answer (score 0):

Also, some IDE's have trouble with the console class (possibly because they are using it themselves to redirect output to a window/dialog)

So a really good work around is using:

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String str = br.readline();
    //or if you want a char
    char i = str.charAt(0);
```

Hope that helps